# how to disable asking for ssh passkey when pushing / pulling to git

Tags: ssh, git, openssh, github

I'm using Github's ssh protocol to push and pull to and from my repo and whenever I do this it shows the following message

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

I want to have an automatic backup script but because of it asking it cant be automatic. how do I stop it from asking for the passphrase

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have password set on your SSH key. To remove password you can use

```
ssh-keygen -p
```

and enter empty password when asked.

If you use that key also for something else, a better approach might be creating a new key without password to use in the automated script.